# How to manage multiple sub folders in VS code in a single project file ? error is showing when i tried to do Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I created a java project in **VS code**. Then in src folder i have 2 classes made namely App.java and  java_1.java. They are perfectly working. But then i tried to make another folder(package) name will_it_work inside the Src folder and added a java class namely it_should_work .  But when i run the code then a error comes
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Pls help how can i manage and create such folders efficiently in VS code
[image: this is the code which i wrote in the class which was made inside the package]

i expect that the classes inserted into the project folder should also be work

Answer (score 0):

##### Don't use **Code Runner**.

Run the code using `run` or `Run Java` provided by the official extension.

[image]